# How to parse whether a string is a valid US currency value

Tags: vb.net

Originally I was using

`Decimal.TryParse(input, New Decimal)`

to figure out of user input is valid money. This works for most cases, except I only want to accept money within 2 digits, so "10.001" should not be accepted.

I looked all over SO for this simple and I imagine common issue but could not find an answer.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253819/unable-to-restrict-number-of-decimal-digits-when-parsing-a-string-to-decimal-in) any help?

Comment: You could also use a NumericUpDown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark in the discussion solved this for me. Thanks! Here's the VB.net code for what I was looking for:

```
 Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("[0-9]?[0-9]?(\.[0-9]?[0-9]$)")
 Dim match As Match = regex.Match(input)
 If Not match.Success Then
```