# Decimal place is zero or not in C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 `double` values

```
double d1 = 3456786.065343

double d2 = 4848484.000000
```

I have to format the numbers only if value after decimal is 0, round up to two zero decimal places e.g 4848484.00

If numbers after decimal is not zero then dont apply any formatting 
E.g  3456786.065343

Comment: well, digging SO will give you some tricks on getting decimals, like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092243/c-sharp-check-if-a-decimal-has-more-than-3-decimal-places)

Comment: Also, if you interested in that level of precision consider using the `decimal` type instead of `double`.

Comment: was my answer helpful to you?  @kishan

Answer (score 4):

You can check if a decimal is an integer or not, if a decimal holds some digits other than 0 after decimal then it is not an integer while otherwise would be true

First case:

```
decimal d = 4848484.000000M;
        if((d % 1) == 0)
        {
         // prints 4848484.00
          Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(d, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); 
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
        }
```

Second case:

```
decimal d1 = 3456786.065343M;
            if((d1 % 1) == 0)
            {
              Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(d1, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); 
            }
            else
            {
                //prints 3456786.065343
                Console.WriteLine(d1.ToString()); 
            }
```

so if a decimal is like `3456786.065343` this will print it as it is.

and if decimal is like `4848484.000000` this will print `4848484.00`

Answer (score 4):

checking if a number has decimal floating points is fairly simple:

```
private void Foo()
        {
            double d2 = 4848484.000000;

            if (d2 - Math.Round(d2) != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d2.ToString());
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d2.ToString("0.00####"));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to format the numbers for display, use a format string of `0.00########`. This will display at least 2 decimal places.

```
var s1 = d1.ToString("0.00####"):
```