# How to validate a currency in dotnet core 2 independent of culture

Tags: .net, validation, currency

For a project I need to validate a currency. 
The requirements are that :

12 is valid
12.1 is valid 
12.12 is also valid
12.123 is not valid.

Now I can use a regex to validate this like this one `[RegularExpression(@"^(?!0\.00)\d{1,3}(.\d{3})*(\,\d\d)?$", ErrorMessage = "Must be a currency with no more then 2 digits after the." )]`

but on tests it failing when someone uses another system. 
So in the Netherlands we use 12,00  and that validates 
but in the US and the UK they use 12.00 and that does not validate

I can also use a validation like this :

```
float num;
bool isValid = float.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Currency,CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), // cached
```

out num);

but then I could not test if the num has only 2 numbers behind the .

I could set a culture but then its wierd for example to enter amounts like 2.45 where they are used to 2,45

Someone a idea how to make the validation work.

Regards,

Roelof

Answer (score 1):

You can parse currency this way:

```
decimal currency = decimal.Parse("123.456", NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

If you don't want to accept three positions after dot you have two ways:

- Your own regular expression to validation
- You can check the decimal result ([C# Check if a decimal has more than 3 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092243/c-sharp-check-if-a-decimal-has-more-than-3-decimal-places)).

If you need float you can cast the decimal result.